# Angular Multistep form - need to have new form elements bind to model

Tags: angularjs, compilation, submit

I have a multi step form where all the input elements bind back to one model that gets loaded with the first request.  Each step will submit the model to the server and a new set of inputs and html will be sent back until the form is completed.

```js
// The function that will be executed on form submit )
$scope.submitForm = function(action) {
    $scope.items['action'] = action;
    //Pass entire model to server and get back new input elements and html
    //I might break this up into a model per step later
    $http.post($scope.url, $scope.items).
    success(function(data, status) {
    // $scope.status = status;

    // Here is where I need to take the variable data and get the new html recompiled into angular.
    document.getElementById("formsteps").innerHTML = data;        

    })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        //$scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        //$scope.status = status;         
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="formsteps" class="row form-horizontal">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

This is not correct.  it merely shows me the text returned.

What is the best way to rebind these new form inputs to an existing model. Compile, apply()?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) or [routes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route). But if your step html dynamicaly generated then you should use some directive with [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service to insert new template in the DOM.